# Cannot access Dash as superuser but can as a guest

Tags: unity-dash

I think I have altered my account settings in 14.04 and Dash stopped working.
Upgraded to 15.04 hoping that would cure the problem but it did not.
Yesterday I could access a terminal and used sudo apt-get to update, install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop, install unity and then sudo shutdown -r now.
Now I cannot access a terminal but as a guest Dash is working normally
Can I recover my correct account settings

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly here. Are you saying that you can't get to your desktop as your regular user? (Dash is not the term for desktop.) What exactly happens when you login from the login screen as your regular user (or don't you get to the login screen at all)? Can you get into a console with CTRL+ALT+F1?

Comment: cannot open up a console with CTRL+ALT+T.

Comment: I have the desktop background but no left or top margin information to help me navigate.

Comment: If I type in a command to try and run a program, like firefox, that appears in a small window in the bottom left of the screen